# Apache rewrite url help, add string in the middle of the url

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I need some help with my apache rewrites since I am quite bad at it.
I want to make an apache rewrite rule where I can rewrite links from my old site format to the new one.

http://foo.bar/old/$1 to http://foo.bar/new/$1. This should also work when old is a random string or empty.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is fairly vague as to what you are attempting to do or what the issue is. I highly recommend reading through these as pages:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer they are both fantastic resources to use when asking or answering questions and will help you get the best answers quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same issue as i did, i found the solution:
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/([-0-9a-zA-Z]*)/(.*)$     http://foo.bar/new/$2